# vb.net: Is it possible to go the line which produced the exception?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Imagine a huge process crashes while it is running, and I have a break point inside the catch block to control it. In the process, the error is: `object not initialized` (or something similar), in some part of the code. I have to do the control of that error.

Is it possible to go once it stopped in debug mode to the line which crashed?

I says this question because I want to avoid to set a lot of breakpoints which sometimes it is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable the setting so that it breaks on all CLR exceptions.  Go to "Debug > Exceptions":

[image]

Then check the box to break on exceptions that are thrown from the CLR:

[image]

Comment: +1  This directly addresses the OP, but, just in case he is unaware, its worth mentioning that the line number is included in the exception's stack trace, so you can always manually find the exact line.